# Supressing "Server Busy" message in dll

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, dll

I am writing a plug-in for Bricscad which is basically just a dll. There are some heavy calculations and I am using multithreading. However while I await for the tasks to complete I get this pop-up. I want so supress this window somehow.

[image]

I've found some solutions but it seems they are not available in .NET.

Accessing PeekMessage() could help as well as using this configuration

```
if (AfxOleGetMessageFilter())
AfxOleGetMessageFilter()->EnableNotRespondingDialog(FALSE);
if (AfxOleGetMessageFilter())
AfxOleGetMessageFilter()->EnableBusyDialog(FALSE)
```

But they are both solutions for c++. Are there any way to supress this window that are available in .NET?

Comment: that suggests the UI is currently unresponsive and so it sounds like your assumption of it being threaded off is incorrect

Comment: This may be the case. The thing is, at some point in code i do WaitAll() call for the threaded calculations to finish and it can possibly cause the UI in the main app to become unresponsive.